# OS X Calendar email alerts — send via Outlook?

Tags: mail.app, ms-office, calendar, alert

I'm using Mac Outlook as my primary email program (my company uses Exchange and it's the "supported" program on Mac), but I've configured Contacts/Calendar to also talk to the Exchange Server.

I like the way Calendar handles alerts, and the fact that it can send *email* reminders, but I'd need them to be sent via Outlook as I'd rather not have 2 copies of my Exchange Inbox on the disk (to save space).

Is there a way to tell Calendar to use Outlook for outgoing email? For now, it asks me to configure Mail.app every time I set a reminder to send email.

Answer (score 1):

- Either you dummy configure Mail so you can access **Preferences** from the **Mail** menu and set in the **General**" pane your default email reader (if not working from Outlook preferences).
- Or you may type in the following in Terminal:

  ```
  defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSHandlers -array-add '{ LSHandlerURLScheme = "mailto"; LSHandlerRoleAll = "com.microsoft.Outlook"; }'
  ```

  This should add an entry to the "**~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist**"

  Using Xcode you add a dictionary item with the two following items:

  ```
  <key>LSHandlerURLScheme</key>
  <string>mailto</string>
  ```

  ```
  <key>LSHandlerRoleAll</key>
  <string>com.microsoft.Outlook</string>
  ```
- Using [**RCDefaultApp**](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) could do the trick but since it hasn't been update since 2009 I'm not sure it's still working.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it seems that mailto: is already configured properly as typing "mailto:address@example.com in the address bar of the browser (or running the command "open mailto:address@example.com") gets me a blank Outlook message with the address in the to: field...

Comment: I've also configured a dummy account in Mail to get to the pref pane and the default Email reader is set to Outlook

Comment: To top it off, leveraging your suggestion, I've run the command `defaults read com.apple.LaunchServices LSHandlers` and the result for mailto: is already what you suggested as a value:

       {
        LSHandlerRoleAll = "com.microsoft.outlook";
        LSHandlerURLScheme = mailto;
    },